# What's the simplest C++11 container to implement?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to try to write my own container, just as an exercise, and I'm aiming to produce something that will work according to the C++11 standard, and I'm also trying to avoid trivial and inefficient implementations like a linked list.

I would like an input about what is the easiest and less verbose container to implement and in what part of the C++11 standard I can find the description of the features that are required by the standard itself.

Comment: But then, iterators, allocators, type traits...

Comment: @MarkGarcia let's start from something ...

Answer (score 9):

You might want to start from [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which is basically a C-style array on steroids.

You might want to implement the basics first, like `begin` and `end` (the `const` and reverse versions can come later), `operator[]`, and the size functions.

Start with `begin` and `end` because:

- With them, you can immediately use some standard algorithms.
- range-for and using iterator for manual iterations

For reference, you can get the [C++11 standard here](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+14882-2012), a link which I got from [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1619294). The specific chapter would be number 23, "Containers library"/[containers].

But the C++ standard is full of standardese and often links around many other parts of it, which makes reading it linearly a pain. You may want to start with [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com) first, which provides accurate descriptions of almost everything in the standard library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374283/whats-the-simplest-c11-container-to-implement#comment32233606_21374435

Answer (score 8):

Strong suggestion: read either of Bjarne Stroustrup's last two books: "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++", or "A Tour of C++".

In both of these books, he walks you through creating your own "vector" container.  It's an informative exercise.

Comment: interesting, I will read "A Tour of C++" since it's more recent.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest is probably `std::array`. Second is probably `std::vector`, which is similar but adds `push_back`, `pop_back` and (more importantly) all the internal code to expand the allocation as needed.

As to the level of difficulty: they're both more work than you probably expect initially. Quite a bit depends on your approach though. You can do a fairly simple approach that contains a fair amount of near-duplication (e.g., between `iterator`, `reverse_iterator`, `const_iterator` and `const_reverse_iterator`), or you can eliminate most of the duplication at the expense of the code being a little trickier.

For references: you're looking primarily at §23.2 and 23.3 of the standard. 23.2 contains requirements for containers in general (most of which apply to both `array` and `vector`) and 23.3 contains requirements specific to sequence containers (array, vector, deque, list, forward_list).

Comment: any reference to the C++11 standard ( I mean the official ISO document ) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like a std::vector.  The underlying container would be something like:

```
T* someArray
```

You allocate the array as needed; create accessor functions etc.  When the array fills up you have to allocate a new array (often double the original size), then copy the elements from the orig array to it.

I'm assuming you just want something to experiment with; not having to mess with std::allocators etc.

Doing a simple dynamic array will help give you insight into how these sort of containers work under the hood.

Comment: I would like to create a container from scratch, so yes, I would like to mess with things ...